# Android application need to detect if the user came back from Google Maps Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, maps

I'm making an App and I use the Google Maps navigation

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + mLat + "," + mLng + "&daddr=" + mLatitude + " , " + mLongitude + ""));
```

And if the user come back from this intent I want to show the rating bar for the place the user has navigated to.
Is startActivityForResult something I can use on Intent not from my application?
Or is there another way to detect the user did came back to my App?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get back something from an Intent you just throw up in the air for Android to handle but...

I'd recommend showing the map within one of your own activity; this way you'd exactly know what the user has done and which pin they've selected.  You can then setResult in that Activity and get back the information.

I know it involves little bit more of development but you'd have total control of the map view and what the user do there.  I'm sure you've seen this but take a look.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

-serkan

Comment: Is it possible to navigate in your own mapview without to much programming?

Comment: I'm not sure how difficult turn-by-turn navigation would be - if that's what you mean by "navigation" Daan, but if you're talking about just allowing user to pan, zoom, switch views from satellite to map, then it's almost all built in.  Also as soon as you implement "onTap()" method, you would know where the user(s) tapped, then you can launch navigation or anything else in that matter...  Please let me know if I can be any further help Daan, Best.